# App not linked when tapping "via MY_APP" of a news feed publication

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

I can't make this working. I've followed all the tutorials on [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/) to make it working but failed.

What are the essential steps to make this "via MY_APP" sentence tappable and link either to my app if installed or the App Store otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you include the following when setting parameters for the feed.

`[params setValue: @"url_link_to_app" forKey: @"link"];`